# Updating a chart while VBA is running

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, charts

I'm trying to see visually what happens to a set of data in Excel each time I increment a driving variable by 1.

The data is visualised in a chart and the increments are done via a for-next loop on an integer n.

Each time I increment n, the values in a table update and the chart should update too. Except it doesn't. The table updates but the chart waits to the end of the routine and shows its position for the last value of n only.

I have put a wait command in, tried Charts("Chart 1").Refresh etc but the chart won't update (albeit the table feeding it does) during the intermediate steps of the code as I'd like it to. I'm on automatic calculation so its not that that's causing the problem.

How do I get the chart to update to the table values whilst the code is running. This was the code sorry.

```
Sub Walkthrough()

Dim n As Integer

For n = 0 To 77
    Range("L3").Value = n
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveChart.Refresh
    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
Next n

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to make it workable:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Walkthrough()

    Dim n As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    For n = 0 To 5
        Range("a1").Value = n
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
    Next n

End Sub
```

Make sure that `A1` is your dependent range in the example. By default the `Application.ScreenUpdating` is set to `True` in Excel, thus you do not need to set it explicitly.

Comment: Sub Walkthrough()

Dim n As Integer

For n = 0 To 77
    Range("L3").Value = n
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveChart.Refresh
    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
Next n


End Sub

Comment: @James - it is a better idea to put your code in the Question... You can format it there.

Comment: So while that code does the job of updating the table and pausing for a second, the chart that's linked to the table doesn't refresh while the code is running. Hence my query

Comment: @James - are you sure that it is `A1`, that is related to your chart? Make `A1` the single source cell and check it again.

Comment: The table that feeds the chart that depends on the value n in the for loop updates perfectly as the routine runs, the calculated values in the table update too. The issue is that the chart that visualises the table does not change to reflect the content of the table (its source data) as the routine runs.

Comment: @James - open a new Excel, select cell A1, press `Alt+F1` and run the routine again.

Answer (score 0):

I had success by activating the chartObjects in the `ActiveSheet`. However, I am not 100% sure about the `DoEvents` calls. Excels selection behavoiur was a bit strange after the procedure finished. Propably because a `ChartObject` was still activated. Therefore, I finally activate the `ActiveSheet`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Walkthrough()

        Dim myChart As ChartObject
        
        For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
            myChart.Activate
            DoEvents
        Next

        ActiveSheet.Activate
        DoEvents

End Sub
```

Comment: I just realised, the question dates a while back! However, solutions may take a while...